# Eloquent Javascript Exercise: Deep Comparison

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning JavaScript and trying to do this exercise:

> Write a function `deepEqual` that takes two values and returns `true` only if they are the same value or are objects with the same properties, where the values
>   of the properties are equal when compared with a recursive call to `deepEqual`.
>
> To find out whether values should be compared directly (use the `===` operator
>   for that) or have their properties compared, you can use the `typeof` operator.
>   If it produces "object" for both values, you should do a deep comparison.
>   But you have to take one silly exception into account: because of a historical
>   accident, `typeof null` also produces "object".
>
> The `Object.keys` function will be useful when you need to go over the properties
>   of objects to compare them.

This is my solution and gives me `true`, `false`, `false` which is wrong

```
function deepEqual (a,b) {
    if (a===b) return true;
    if (typeof a=="object" && typeof b=="object") {         
        let x=Object.keys(a), y=Object.keys(b);
        if (x.lenght==y.lenght) {
            for (key of x){
                if (y.includes(key)){
                    if (a[key]===b[key]) return true;
                    else return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    } 
}

let obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));    
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
```

This is the right solution:

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
        b == null || typeof b != "object") return false;
    let keysA = Object.keys(a), keysB = Object.keys(b);
    if (keysA.length != keysB.length) return false;
    for (let key of keysA) {
        if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


let obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

I can't really understand what's wrong with what I wrote and how can I fix it.

Thank you very much for helping a noobie :)

Comment: You're not diving into nested objects; this is a classic recursion problem. `length` is spelled wrong.

Comment: I tried:

`function deepEqual (a,b){

    if (a===b) return true;

    if (typeof a=="object" && typeof b=="object") {

        let x=Object.keys(a), y=Object.keys(b);

        if (x.lenght==y.lenght) {
            for (key of x){
                if (y.includes(key)){
                    if (a[key]===b[key]) return true;
                    else return false;
                }
            }
        } return true;
          else return false;
    } else return false;

}
let obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));`

But still not working..

Comment: That's illegible as a comment. `length` is still spelled wrong, and it's still not diving into nested objects.

Comment: Break the solution and map to what you have written. You will easily see at what all points your solution is not doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the issues in your code:

**1) The test for objects:**

```
if (typeof a=="object" && typeof b=="object") {
```

This is fine, but what if this condition is not true? You don't have any code that deals with that case, so the function will return `undefined`. It should return `false` instead.

Secondly, there is this weird thing in JavaScript about which the question has warned you -- you should have taken it into account:

> ...because of a historical accident, `typeof null` also produces "object".

...so you need to have a separate test for that, as `null` is not *really* an object and code will produce errors when you treat it as one.

In your code a `null` value would pass this `if` test and would then execute `Object.keys(null)`, which triggers an exception. A `null` value should not be allowed in there.

**2) Comparing the number of properties**

```
    if (x.lenght==y.lenght) {
```

There is a spelling mistake. It is not `lenght`, but `length` (2x).
And again, what if this condition is not true? There is no code that deals with that case, except for the `return true` *after* that `if` block, yet your function should then return `false`.

**3) Check that a property exists in both objects**

```
            if (y.includes(key)){
```

This test works, but is not optimal. `includes` is slower than just checking that `key in b` (it is a pity that the reference solution also uses `includes`).

And as before, what if this condition is not true? The function should immediately exit the loop and return `false`, but this is not happening...

**4) Check that the values for the same properties are *deep* equal.**

```
                if (a[key]===b[key]) return true;
```

This condition does not do a *deep* comparison. The question already told you what to do here:

> ...where the values of the properties are equal when compared with a recursive call to `deepEqual`

So here is that occasion where you should perform a recursive call, so any nested objects are compared in the same way. Just `a[key]===b[key]` will be `false` when these two values are separate objects. But the condition should really be `true` when those objects have the same properties, and same values for them... which is exactly what your function is able to do: so *call* it here.

Secondly, this is not the time to `return true`, as this will exit the loop without checking also the other keys, and there the outcome could be negative... And one "negative" is enough to make the overall end result `false`. So while things are good, you should *continue* the loop.

**5) When the values are different**

```
                else return false;
```

Yes, this is the right time to `return false`.

**6) When all tests succeeded**

```
    return true;
```

This is the only right place to `return true`, but you should solve the second remark in my answer so this statement is *not* executed when the lengths are different.

#### The correct code

As you already have correct code to compare with, it is a bit overkill to repeat that code here.

Comment: You helped me so much,thank you a lot!
i changed to this but is still not working:

`code`function deepEqual (a,b){
 if (a===b) return true;
 if (typeof a==null || typeof b==null)return false;
 else {
  if (typeof a=="object" && typeof b=="object") {
   let x=Object.keys(a), y=Object.keys(b);
   if (x.length==y.length) {
    for (key of x){
     if (y.includes(key)){
      if (deepEqual(a[key], b[key]));
      else return false;
     } return true;
     else return false;
    }
   } return true;
   else return false;
  } return true;
  else return false;
 }
}`code`

Comment: it gives an error at the second "else return false"
the error is "  Unexpected token 'else'  "

Sorry is i didn't post a well formatted code but i'm new to the forum and don't know how to insert code in comments

Comment: Several things: `typeof a==null` is never true. Please read that key phrase in the question which I quoted? When `a === null`, then `typeof a === "object"`. You should just test `a===null`.

Comment: You are using the `else` keyword at places where it has no corresponding `if` to offset against. Indent your code properly to detect where an `else` is just hanging without corresponding `if`.

Comment: Although `if (deepEqual(a[key], b[key]));`is correct syntax, this is bad practice and leads to mistakes: the semicolon indicates "then do nothing". It is better to turn the condition around like this: `if (!deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;` without `else`. Notice the exclamation mark (logical negation)

Comment: I checked multiple times... to me it looks like if every else has its is... Maybe there is something basic i'm not understanding.

https://ibb.co/3TVZnTr

Comment: At each `if` you have a `return true` after the `if` block. That cannot be when you want to do `else`. An `else` should follow immediately after the `if` block. I had also written in my answer where the *only* good place was to put `return true` and why you should not do a `return true` inside the loop. Did you understand that part?

Comment: so if the function encounters a return will automatically exit giving that return?
I understood that the return inside the loop would stop the loop and imediately return what is written as a result, not allowing the program to do the full loop cycle

But still can't understand why if i put those returns it gives me error.

Since if/else structure is:

if (condition) {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}



why can't i write:

if(condition){return true}
else(condition){return false}

Comment: But that is not what you wrote. You have `if (condition) { block } return false; else ...` You cannot have that block ***and*** `return false` ***and*** `else`. The `else` must be right after the `{ block }`. If you want to return when the `if` is true, that `return` must be *inside* the block. And yes, `return` exits the function with the supplied return value; it does not depend on whether it is in a loop or not. The function stops executing whatever it was doing, and the caller gets the value.

Comment: I want to also repeat what I wrote in the answer. You should not do a `return true` if you have not checked *all* the properties of the objects. When the first values are equal you cannot yet be sure that *all* other properties will have the same values, so you should *not* do `return true` upon a first success. There is only success when the complete object scan is positive for *all* properties. So don't do `return true` inside the loop. The loop must first do all its iterations to completion.

Comment: The opposite is however different. *As soon as* you find the first difference between the two objects there is no use in continuing the loop. Whatever the result of the other comparisons would be, you already found one difference, so just stop looking further and exit immediately with `return false`.